# Use only subset of JPQL select columns for objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have entities Team, Game and TeamInGame. To select teams ordered by their last games i use:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select tg.team, max(tg.game.gameDate) as maxDate" +
" from TeamInGame tg" +
" group by tg.team" +
" order by maxDate desc");

return Lists.transform(query.getResultList(), new Function<Object[], Team>() {
            @Override
            public Team apply(Object[] input) {
                return (Team) input[0];
            }
       });
```

Is there a way to get rid of this transformation? This query does not work:

```
return em.createQuery("select tg.team, max(tg.game.gameDate) as maxDate" +
    " from TeamInGame tg" +
    " group by tg.team" +
    " order by maxDate desc", Team.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: When you say "...this query does not work...", do you get an exception?  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no.  You can't `order by` in JPQL without having the sort key be defined in the `select` clause, and you can't convince the `TypedQuery` to not return the elements in the `select` clause, because that's what a query does!

Personally, I think the Transform approach you've got is the cleanest, code-wise.  Next best would be something like what @SJuan76 suggested using [JPQL Constructor Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).  Perhaps you could even do it with a copy constructor on `Team` itself, so that you don't have to create an intermediate `TeamResult` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own object that holds the data and populate it from JPQL. For example:

```
  ...("select new myPackage.TeamResult(tg.team, max(tg.game.gameDate)) from ..."
```

TeamResult has to both:

a) have a constructor that matches the parameters.

b) be fully qualified.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to use the date returned. And I think that both in terms of readability and performance (I don't really bother about performance currently and plan to optimize it only when needed) trasfrom using function is better.

Answer (score 0):

"This query doesn't work" - Are you getting an exception?
Also, is it possible for you to add an attribute for maxDate in your Team entity?
Not sure if this works in JPQL, but you may try the following:

select a.teamid from
(select teamid, max(g.gamedate) as maxdate from teamingame tg, game g where tg.gameId = g.pk 
group by teamid order by maxdate desc) as a